# sass prepend root class to current selector

Tags: css, sass

I am having trouble prepending the root class to my current selector in sass.  I have the following code:

```sass
.cta-two-columns {
  &__text-holder {
    @at-root&#{__inner} {

    // also tried @at-root __inner&{#}
    // and many others like  @at-root__inner

      padding: rem(25px);
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives me the following:

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder__inner {
  padding: rem(25px);
}
```

I don't understand the above - what's the point of `at-root` as you may as well just do `&__inner`as it gave me the same as the two things I have shown I tried

how do I get

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder .cta-two-columns__inner {
}
```

without having to resort to

```sass
.cta-two-columns {
  &__text-holder {
    .cta-two-columns__inner {
      padding: rem(25px);
    }
  }
}
```

Or is this the only way to do it in sass?

Comment: You can also put `&` in a variable (for example `$self:&;`) and than use it with __inner. Something like `#{$self}__inner`. But well, it's not that different from the last code you wrote... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@at-root` doesn't really work like you may think in this case. `@at-root` will simply make the declaration outside the  nest. To better understand, add another CSS declaration like below:

```
.cta-two-columns {
  &__text-holder {

    margin: 10px;
    @at-root&#{__inner} {

      padding: rem(25px);
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce the following CSS code:

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder {
  margin: 10px;
}
.cta-two-columns__text-holder__inner {
  padding: rem(25px);
}
```

Simply imagine how the selector will be created without  `@at-root` then make it outside.

Without it will produce this:

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder {
  margin: 10px;
}
.cta-two-columns__text-holder .cta-two-columns__text-holder__inner {
  padding: rem(25px);
}
```

Then we simply omit `.cta-two-columns__text-holder`.

---

One idea to obtain what you want is to consider a variable where you can declare the main class then you will be able to nest as many element as you want:

```
$sel: '.cta-two-columns';

#{$sel}__text-holder {
   #{$sel}__inner {
    padding: rem(25px);
  }
}
```

Will produce:

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder .cta-two-columns__inner {
  padding: rem(25px);
}
```

with more nested elements:

```
$sel: '.cta-two-columns';

#{$sel}__text-holder {
   #{$sel}__outer {
      #{$sel}__inner{
        #{$sel}__wrap{
          padding: rem(25px);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will produce

```
.cta-two-columns__text-holder .cta-two-columns__outer .cta-two-columns__inner .cta-two-columns__wrap {
  padding: rem(25px);
}
```