# Less: How to reference parent in nth-child

Tags: css, less

This is what I have :

Less :

```
.parent{
  &-caption{
    color:red;
  }

  &:first-child{
    border: solid blue !important;
    &-caption{
      color:blue !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Html

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">One</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">Two</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">Three</div>
</div>
```

**Problem** : But the first child's caption's color does not become blue.

Is this possible in LEss ? I know it's possible in Sass.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `&:first-of-type`?

Comment: this will probably help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54699529/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Your less compiles to the following css:

```
.parent-caption {
  color: red;
}
.parent:first-child {
  border: solid blue !important;
}
.parent:first-child-caption {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

As you can see, that isn't really valid css. There is a [playground](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/) on the less css site that allows you to preview how your css code is compiled.

I would recommend you just do something like this

```css
.parent .parent-caption {
  color: red;
}
.parent:first-of-type .parent-caption {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">One</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">Two</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-caption">Three</div>
</div>
```

You can do this in Less like so:

```
.parent {
  &-caption {
    color: red;
  }
  &:first-of-type &-caption{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

The explanation for this feature is on the [features page](http://lesscss.org/features/) of Less css under the Parent Selectors heading.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but your code doesn't work, it doesn't select the first-child of the parent, then inside that the caption.
first-of-type on the caption doesn't do anything, because there's only one caption in each div anyway